# My Lex and Yacc program runs once fine, then crashes on the second try?

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

I have two VERY tiny files (in an attempt to remove all other confounding variables) written in Lex and Yacc, respectively.

Lex:

```
%{
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include "y.tab.h"
    void yyerror(char *);
%}

%%

[a] {
    yylval = *yytext;
    return VAR;
    }

[ \t\n] ;

. yyerror("invalid character");

%%

int yywrap(void) {
 return 1;
}
```

Yacc:

```
%token VAR

%{
    void yyerror(char *);
    int yylex(void);
    #include <stdio.h>
%}

%%

butts:
    VAR { printf("%d\n", $1); }

%%

void yyerror(char *s) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s);
}


int main(void) {
    #if YYDEBUG
    yydebug = 1;
    #endif
    yyparse();
    return 0;
}
```

and when I compile the whole thing (with the -DYYDEBUG) option, I get the output:

```
Starting parse
Entering state 0
Reading a token: a
Next token is token VAR ()
Shifting token VAR ()
Entering state 1
Reducing stack by rule 1 (line 12):
   $1 = token VAR ()
97
-> $$ = nterm butts ()
Stack now 0
Entering state 2
Reading a token: a
Next token is token VAR ()
syntax error
Error: popping nterm butts ()
Stack now 0
Cleanup: discarding lookahead token VAR ()
Stack now 0
```

when inputing "a" twice. The first time I press "a" when it asks `Reading a token:`the program seems to run fine, but the second time, it vomits.

I am at a loss as to why this is so.

Comment: FWIW, "crash" usually means a segfault or some such, while I would interpret "vomit" to mean "produces huge amounts of useless output". If Brian's answer is correct, the actual problem symptom would be "the second time it reports a syntax error". Accurate problem descriptions make finding problems much easier. There's nothing wrong with a bit of informality or humour, but when reporting a problem, it is always good to clearly state (1) what happened; (2) what you expected to happen; and (3) how these differ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your grammar file says that only one "a" is permitted. Any more is an error, and thus you get an error. Your grammar rule says:

```
butts: VAR
```

nothing more, nothing less.

Thus the only valid program that your grammar matches is:

```
a
```

Any other input, such as:

```
aa
```

or:

```
a
a
```

Will cause a syntax error. Your rule very explicitly says **one** VAR **only**; not a sequence of VARS; not a few vars. Just one VAR.

If you want it to match more than one in the input, you **have** to say so. The grammar thus has to describe the permitted sequence:

```
butts: VAR | butts VAR
```

Then it will permit the sequence.

Is that clearer?

Comment: So in short, butts should be allowed to be both butts (starting a recursive tree) AND var, which is an end of a branch (a single solution)?